# how to Create a script that takes a list of words as input and prints only words that appear exactly once

Tags: linux, unix

Requirements for input and output files:

Input format: One line, one word
Output format: One line, one word

Words should be sorted

I tried to use this command to solve this question

```
sort list | uniq
```

but it fails.

Anyone who can help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
cat <file_name> | sort | uniq -c | grep -e '^\s.*1\s' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Explanation:

- cat <file_name> | sort | uniq -c --> Will print all the entries, sort them and print count of each name.
- grep -e '^\s.*1\s' --> This is a regex which will exclude all the entries where count is not 1
- awk is used to remove count and print just name

Comment: is there any other command line you can use without using awk

Comment: I used 'awk' to display only 2nd column. Though 'awk' is the most simple way of doing it, but this can also be done by 'cut' command:

cat <file_name> | sort | uniq -c | grep -e '^\s.*1\s' | rev | cut -d' ' -f 1 | rev

Comment: what error are you getting? Also, please specify your input file

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice, simple and elegant to use this command to perform this task.

```
cat <file_name> | sort |uniq -u
```

And it would do the task perfectly.

Comment: Your answer shows all the words and the amount of times they are used, it does not filter out the ones which are used multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Evans Fone assisted me.

If you're trying to implement a script that runs as:

```
cat list | ./scriptname
```

Then do the following:

Step 1:
Type

```
emacs scriptname
```

Step 2:
Press

```
ENTER
```

Step 3:
Type

```
!/bin/bash
sort |uniq -u
```

Step 4:
Press

```
CTRL+X
CTRL+S
CTRL+X
CTRL+C
```

Answer (score 0):

sort | uniq -u

as simple as that.
sort without argument prompts input sorts its and pipe it to unique which print unique words